# How to replace & generate line number

Tags: text-processing, numbering

I have an input file with below data, how can I convert it to below mentioned output file.

Input file

```
00001abc
00002def
00003ghi
00001jkl
00002mno
00003pqr
00001stu
00002vwx
00003yza
00004bcd
```

Output file

```
00001abc
00002def
00003ghi
00004jkl
00005mno
00006pqr
00007stu
00008vwx
00009yza
00010bcd
```

Comment: is this is the only line you want to change or have you just posted it for example? And, is this a file or data in a file? Nothing is clear.

Answer (score 3):

Another `awk` approach.

```
awk -F'[0-9]+' '{printf("%05d%s\n",NR,$2)}' infile >newfile
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
awk '{ printf "%05d%s\n",NR,substr($1,6)}' input_file > output_file
```

where

- `printf "%05d" .. NR` will output line number (`NR` (Number of record)) padded with 0
- `substr($1,6)` will extract substring of `$1` (first argument) starting from 6

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` to delete the existing digits from the start of each line, and `nl` to number the lines in the specific manner:

```
$ sed 's/^[0-9]*//' file | nl -n rz -s '' -w 5
00001abc
00002def
00003ghi
00004jkl
00005mno
00006pqr
00007stu
00008vwx
00009yza
00010bcd
```

The `nl` options asks for zero-filled numbers (`-n rz`, which also right-justifies the numbers, but this is unimportant here) with no delimiter between the line numbers and the data (`-s ''`). The numbers are five digits wide (`-w 5`).

[`nl` is a POSIX utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/nl.html).

Answer (score 0):

With sh

```
while read a;do i=$((i+1));printf "%05d%s\n" $i "${a##*[0-9]}";done < infile > outfile
```

inplace replacement

```
printf '%s\n' $(while read a;do i=$((i+1));printf "%05d%s\n" $i "${a##*[0-9]}";done < infile) > infile
```